# Random shuffling an array 2 elements by 2

Tags: algorithm, shuffle

My question is related to the alghoritm more than the programming language so feel free to use any language to explain me.

I have an array and I want to shuffle it in a random way, anyway shuffling has to involve 2 elements at the time.
So, if I have:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

`1-2,3-4,5-6`,etc. pairs have to be shuffled together leading, for example, to the following

```
3 4 7 8 9 10 1 2 5 6
```

Comment: And how should those pairs be decided? Do they have to be back to back always?

Comment: Please use the tag feature appropiately. The question is language agnostic and as such shouldn't contain random tags.

Comment: How will you decide the pairs? What happens if the array length is odd?

Comment: yes rohit, pairs are back to back so, starting from 1, 1-2, 3-4,5-6 and so on!(you can thus assume an even length for the array) Fema what is the right tag?

Comment: Array length will always be even, you can take this as initial assumption. Pairs are decided by natural number sequence ordering, so it will always be first element with second element, third with fourth...

Comment: Could you explain your shuffling syntax? What does 1-2, 3-4 etc. denotes? How does this produce the output for the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as a normal shuffle, except you're viewing the "shuffle array" as half the size of the actual array. Meaning `1,2,3,4,5,6` would actually be an array `1 2, 3 4, 5 6`.

Here's some psuedocode using [fisher yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1) in pairs of 2:
  for i from (n − 1) / 2 downto 1 do
       j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
       exchange a[j * 2] and a[i * 2]
       exchange a[j * 2 + 1] and a[i * 2 + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with the indices of the pairs, that is use an array twice smaller than the input array, use `std::random_shuffle`(in `C++`) on it and then change the original array according to your helper array.